# App store approval process for Hybrid Apps

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I want to know what is the process that apple follows to approve a hybrid app (developed using PhoneGap) submitted to the App Store?

I read that ***PhoneGap*** is approved by Apple as a framework for building native apps but couldn't find any guidelines for the same.

So i would like to know some key points that should be taken into consideration while developing hybrid apps that will prevent it from being rejected on the app store.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

check out the point 12.3 in particular

Comment: So it is considered as any other native app?

Comment: Yes it is, until unless the build which you created is broken(with respect to the iOS standards)

Comment: The links are behind Apple's paywall.